# Simplifying surd of degree 1/4 to 1/2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What will be the simplification of

> $$\sqrt { 6 } \cdot \sqrt { 2-\sqrt { 3 }  } $$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> $$\sqrt { 6 } \cdot \sqrt { 2-\sqrt { 3 }  } =\sqrt { 3 } \cdot \sqrt { 2 } \sqrt { 2-\sqrt { 3 }  } =\sqrt { 3 } \sqrt { 4-2\sqrt { 3 }  } =\sqrt { 3 } \sqrt { { \left( \sqrt { 3 } -1 \right)  }^{ 2 } } \\=\sqrt { 3 } \left( \sqrt { 3 } -1 \right) = 3-\sqrt { 3 }  $$

Comment: I can't thank you enough man! I have been trying to do it for 20 mins.thank you again!!!!

Comment: you are welcome)